# Unwanted log with new IExceptionHandler in .net8

Tags: .net

I use the new way to handle exceptions in .net8 with IExceptionHandler for logging all unhandled exceptions

But every time there is a new exception unhandled i have an unwanted log from this method "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsTelemetry.ReportUnhandledException"

It's like when there is a new exception thrown ReportUnhandledException is executed in first and my ExceptionHandler in second

My program.cs :

```csharp
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var config = builder.Configuration
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "DOTNET_")
             .Build();

// Logging
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
builder.Host.UseNLog(new NLogAspNetCoreOptions() { RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false });

builder.Services
    .Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => { options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto; })
    .ConfigureHealthChecks(config);

builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.ConfigureConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddServices(config);


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler();
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app
    .UseHttpsRedirection()
    .UseHealthChecks("/healthz", new HealthCheckOptions
    {
        Predicate = _ => true,
        ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
    });

app.MapControllers();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.Run();
```

My implementation of IExceptionHandler

```csharp
 internal sealed class GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> logger) : IExceptionHandler
 {
     private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionHandler> _logger = logger;

     public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(
         HttpContext httpContext,
         Exception exception,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);

         var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
         {
             Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
             Title = "Internal Server Error",
             Detail = exception.Message
         };

         httpContext.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;

         await httpContext.Response
             .WriteAsJsonAsync(problemDetails, cancellationToken);

         return true;
     }
 }
```

My expectation is to only have one log for my exception instead of two

Comment: What log? Can you please add code resulting in the exception and how it is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by setting Exception Handler Middleware logging to None in appsettings.json.

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware": "None"
```